# How do I topologically clean "pointy bridges" using GRASS v.clean?

Tags: grass-gis, topology, self-intersection

I have a shapefile with hundreds of pointy areas connected at the tip, forming a "pointy bridge". This creates a self-intersection and duplicate node. I'm not exactly sure what this type of error is called, so I do not know which `v.clean` parameters to use. How do I fix this using `v.clean`? I do not care about splitting the bridge vs. merging the bridge - just want to get rid of the error.

The last thing I tried was running `v.clean` with these parameters, and it did nothing:

`break:0 
 bpol:0 
 rmdupl:0 
 rmbridge:0 
 rmdac:0`

[image: sp00ky pointy bridge]

Comment: what do  you get from v.info -t? what's the origin of your polygons? i've faced this problem before and the way around i tried was doing a small negative buffer

Comment: v.info -t:
nodes=89424
points=0
lines=0
boundaries=110503
centroids=25545
areas=74354
islands=53275
primitives=136048
map3d=0

Comment: I don't think doing a small negative buffer will be the best solution for me unfortunately because my file is huge and the computer is very slow. It would take hours/maybe days. I will keep it in mind if no other solutions come up, however!

Comment: When it comes to self-intersections, I tend to use the `snap` tool which snaps the lines closer to nearest vertex within the given threshold. You may need to play with this a few times as this could also affect other parts of your shapefile :)

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed as follows:

1. Creating a small test study to work on. It should contain those overlapping vertex points.
2. Apply the v.clean algorithm, fine-tuning the break parameter.
3. Once happy with the threshold value, run it on the whole dataset.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to *v.clean* help, section *rmbridge*

> A bridge is an area type connection of an island (polygon in a
>   polygon) to the outer polygon. This is topologically incorrect (but
>   OGC Simple Features allow it).

This is what you have here, as rings inside your polygons are connected together.

Therefore, as @Elio Diaz suggested, the best solution would be to go with a buffer, though I'd go with a small positive value (0.01 m or less, depending on your dataset), in order to separate the different rings without making a notable difference on the dataset.

Then you should have no more errors in your layer, or be able to clean them easily.

The problem you have in your dataset is that the points have to be identical to represent your rings, but this is not allowed  by topology. Using the buffer method and separating the rings, even with a hair, is enough to correct this behaviour.